# How to do the nested count in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregate

I have the email messaging app that uses the DB schema that looks like this:

```
db={
  "archives": [
    {
      "header": {
        "subject": "message-1",
        "message-id": "a"
      }
    },
    {
      "header": {
        "subject": "Re:message-1",
        "message-id": "b",
        "reply-to": [
          "a"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "header": {
        "subject": "Re:message-1",
        "message-id": "c",
        "reply-to": [
          "a"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "header": {
        "subject": "message-2",
        "message-id": "d"
      }
    },
    {
      "header": {
        "subject": "Re:message-2",
        "message-id": "e",
        "reply-to": [
          "d"
        ],
        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can list all starting emails (those without the `reply-to` tag) like this:

```
db.archives.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "header.reply-to": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  }
])
```

That shows me that only `message-id: a` and `message-id: d` are the starting emails:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "header": {
      "message-id": "a",
      "subject": "message-1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "header": {
      "message-id": "d",
      "subject": "message-2"
    }
  }
]
```

What I am unable to figure out is how to get the count of replies to each starting email. In this example:

- Message-ID: **A** has **2** replies
- Message-ID: **D** has **1** reply

I posted this example on the MongoDB playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/H6IT0SfCqBp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$lookup` with same collection, pass `header.message-id` as localField and pass `header.reply-to` as foreignField
- `$size` to get total elements in `repliesCount` array

```
db.archives.aggregate([
  { $match: { "header.reply-to": { $exists: false } } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "archives",
      localField: "header.message-id",
      foreignField: "header.reply-to",
      as: "repliesCount"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { repliesCount: { $size: "$repliesCount" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GuSi3rKjqj2)

Comment: I am not sure how, but I've done multiple comparisons and your code is performing about 20 times faster than that of Minsky, which was already pretty fast. This is awesome, thanks a lot.

Comment: this approach will use index if you have specified an index. remember this thing, if you match your condition in or after second stage then this will not use index.